# Custom Button on Campaign History

Tags: page-layout, campaign, campaign-member

I want to create a button for the Campaign History related list on the Lead page layout.  I am able to create such a button (Customize -> Campaign -> Campaign Members -> Buttons and Links) and set the Display Type to be 'List Button'.  I then go to the Lead page layout, and to the Campaign History related list, but there is no option to add the custom button.  Has anyone got this to work?

Comment: Weird because I can do it, just tried. Are you sure you selected List Button ? What's the content source of the button ?

Comment: Brovasi, content source for testing is javascript (alert('hello')), but will be VF page in reality.  Can you paste a screenshot?

Comment: I created a button call 'Test Hamayoun'. I added 2 screenshot in an answer.

Comment: Thanks very much!  Can you do a screenshot for the button configuration itself?

Comment: Sure no problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lead Edit Page Layout**
[image: Lead Edit Page Layout]

**Lead Page Layout**
[image]

**Campaign Button Config**
[image]

Comment: Got it.  The issue was to add the List Button on the Campaign object, not on the Campaign Member object.  Thanks brovasi.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you cannot modify that related list. In fact, I don't think you can modify "history" related lists.